# Setting Debug points for a Chainlit application

Tags: python, visual-studio, debugging, ide, cursor

I've built my first chainlit app. It's very simple and it runs like this.

Starting backend:
cd ./chainlit-backend
chainlit run app.py -h

Start the React app:
cd ./frontend
npm i
npm run dev

How do I get it where I can set break points in my IDE and debug? I'm currently using cursor but I have VS code and intellij as well. Any guidance would be amazing-- I would love to move forward but I think I'll be stumped until I can play around with breakpoints. Thank you

I've tried -d debug mode. I've tried setting breakpoints. I'm not seeing how to do this :(